# trouble getting started with Django nonrel and gae

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm having a hard time getting started with Django nonrel and GAE. I've followed the instructions here: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine Which explain how to install Django nonrel. When I run the project using Google App Engine Launcher, it seems to be working because I see the "It works!" page.

But I'm trying to go through the examples in the Django book and I don't see what I expect to see. The book talks about having a views.py file where I add my own views, but I don't see this file in the root of my project directory. I do see urls.py.

Am I missing something? Do I need to run some .py script from django nonrel once I finish copying over the files listed in the django nonrel tutorial? Do I just create this file on my own, even though the book says that it should have been created for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to add your app to the project. Running `python manage.py startapp myapp` in your project directory will create a new folder for you to add your views, models, forms and such.